# Dataset column variable from string vector

Tags: r, string, variables

I have a problem to create a dataset column variable from string vector. I watched many tutorials and this forum question without answer.
This is a dummy code

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
vector = c('wfns','age')
loc <- as.name(vector[1])
aSAH$loc
```

I tried as.name, as.symbol, eval(parser), and i have NULL as output. 
**My objecive is to use vector[1] as variable name : aSAH$wfns.**
Thank you

Comment: Do you just want `df[vector] <- NA` ?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with your dataframe. The question is quite unclear.

Comment: My objecive is to use vector[1] as variable name : aSAH$wfns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by this way :

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
vector_names = c('wfns','age')
Variables_vector_index = c()
for (i in 1:length(vector_names)){
  Variables_vector_index = c(Variables_vector_index,grep(vector_names[i], colnames(aSAH)))
}

aSAH[Variables_vector_index[1]]
```

This is equivalent to aSAH$wfns

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want the loc column to be "wfns" ? 
If that is the case, you can use the dplyr package and the mutate function

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
vector = c('wfns','age')
loc <- as.name(vector[1])

#Use dplyr
library(dplyr)
aSAH <- aSAH%>%mutate(loc = vector[[1]])
```

For a conventional approach,you can loop through and add columns (given you are starting with 7 columns already in the table), the following works.

```
for ( i in 1:length(vector) ) {

                           aSAH[,i+7] <- vector[[i]] 
                           colnames(aSAH)[[i]] <- vector[[i]]

                              }
```

If you mean something else the question is not very clear.